# In Android, is it possible to get the first version of the app the user installed from the Play store?

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services

I have an app currently in alpha, and I am thinking of moving to beta soon.
Once I do this step, I want to re-initialize local files as the game changed quite a bit (local scores, etc.), and display a "Thank you for testing the alpha-version"-message and whatnot.

To do this, I would like to check whether the first time the user installed my app from the app-store was during the alpha, i.e. whether the version corresponds to one of the version of alpha.
I found that it is possible to get [the time the app was first installed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime), but haven't found a way to retrieve the version.

Short story long: is there a way to get the version of the app the user installed it for the first time?

P.S.
If possible, I would like to achieve this in Unity

Comment: Because you're moving to beta doesn't it automatically destroy data from alpha?

Comment: Not sure if it destroys the local data I generate (binary .gd files) and it wouldn't help me for the message thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect a way of doing this would be to push a small update on your alpha version to include a boolean variable (eg. alphaVersionPlayer == true) in the save data to declare that this save was made during an alpha version?

then just check true/false on that for additional rewards or thank you messages.

(disclaimer: I'm undoubtedly less experienced than you at programming and using unity, I'm just getting started)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did that, but the problem with this solution is that I am not sure if the data is preserved between installs, and I am pretty sure it is not if the cash or appdata is cleaned. This is why I would like to retrieve the info from the PlayStore.

Comment: @Giezi This method should work. When you update apps you do not lose any of the saved data (otherwise updating a game would mean you'd have to start over again). The only way for a user to override this would be if they have a rooted phone and they specifically delete this data, in which case they just won't get a "thank you" for testing the alpha version, which doesn't really matter.

Comment: ok, thanks. I had some strange behaviors, but I think it was caused by me switching back and forth from the development version to the play-store version